# What does a "chatty" CSOM API mean?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, content-migration

I've just begun the process of migrating on-prem SharePoint to SharePoint Online, and I'll be using Metalogix's Content Matrix migration tool.

When reading the documentation, it mentions that the migration tool uses a fairly chatty API (CSOM). When discussing performance limitations of migration:

> The very **chatty** nature of the CSOM API that is the primary API used for migration to SharePoint Online, compounded by the distance required for each API call to travel between on-prem environments and SPO.

The only context of *chatty* that I'm familiar with is network activity. Is that what this is referring to? If so, and if possible, could someone please provide any explanation of why an API (such as CSOM) might have intentionally been developed as *chatty*?

Comment: It *is* referring to network activity. This isn't a strictly-SharePoint question (except that the quote claims CSOM is chatty).

Answer (score 2):

Chatty means it require lot of communications back and forth to achieve a task. But there are ways around it.

For example: You can keep loading the request to server using `context.Load`.. and once its all loaded you can fire `executequery`